# Kendo Legend not showing

Tags: kendo-chart

I have the following codes below.

```
    .chartBody {
        width: 350px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    <div class="chartBody" id="genreStrucChart"></div>
```

---

```
    $("#genreStrucChart").kendoChart({
                dataSource: setData(),
                series: [
                    { field: "Sample" },
                    { field: "School" }
                ],
                categoryAxis: {
                    field: "Counter"
                },
                legend: {
                    visible: true,
                    position: "bottom"
                }
            });
```

---

The codes above works fine expect it's not showing the "Legend". What seems to be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The legend is built off the series.name property.  You could change it to:

```
series: [
    { field: "Sample", name: "Sample" },
    { field: "School", name: "School" }
],
```

and that should make your legend show up.  I had the same problem and went through much agony before I figured out that was the problem.  I hope that helps you.

Comment: Sorry for unrelated note -  can anyone help me with this kendo question -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934532/access-items-of-bar-chart-kendo-ui

Comment: I've faced with a similar problem, but I have a pie-like chart. In case you have a pie chart, the category field is required for every data item. Also you can customize it using the series.categoryField property